# Passing data to Django view using Python requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

In my Django view, i'm creating a system where an user submits a form or a button. After that, my Django view sends a request to an external Python script, this script receives the request, retrieves some data about that user and sends this data as a response to the Django view, which will perform some operations with this data (show it to the user and so on), all of that is made using Python-Requests. So the external Python script works like a microservice.

I'm able to send the request, and i also managed to make my view receive the response from the external Python script, i only have a problem with authentication.

Here is how i send data to the Django view:

```
import json

import requests

session = requests.session()
token = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginview/')

session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginview/',
             data={
                 'username': 'USER',
                 'password': 'PASSWORD',
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token})

token = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myTestView/')
data = json.dumps({'test': 'value'})
session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myTestView/',
             data={
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token,
                 'data': data})
```

This is what happens here: a request with some credentials is sent, then the `login` view authenticates those credentials, if the credentials are authenticated, the data is printed by `myTestView`.

Here are my views:

```
@login_required
def myTestView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        print(json.loads(data))
        print('received.')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response    

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('authenticated')
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('wrong username or password')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response
```

This code works, the only problem is that instead of USERNAME and PASSWORD there should be the username and the password of the user who is using the service. Since the external script sends data about `user1`, only `user1` should read that data.

So if `user1` is using the view, the username should be `user1` and the password should be `USER1PASS`. Same if the view is used by user2 and so on.

At the actual stage, to send data to an user i need to change the following code manually. Instead, i need a way to send to Django the user's credentials, here is the snippet involved:

```
session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginview/',
             data={
                 'username': 'USER',
                 'password': 'PASSWORD',
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token})
```

I don't know if the question was clear enough. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Jack! Could you please clarify on how do you trigger the external script? You say it works like microservice, so what handles requests going to it? If you provide this piece of code it will be easier to suggest a way to pass credentials into your script.

Comment: Hey! The external script in the most common case is triggered when the page is loaded. Once the page is loaded, the view is called and sends the request. I'm also planning to add a feature to trigger it with a form or a button, but i still haven't done it - this is why i did not add it to the question

Comment: I can't understand is the script running on the separate server or on the same as django?

Comment: On a separate server!

Comment: Nice. Then you need to implement something like one-time-password django model on the server side where you will keep user, datetime and token generated for each request. When you call the external script pass there security security token (not csrf) generated for this user. Modify login_view to authenticate request using token instead of username and password. Also you should implement token validation using current datetime in login_view.

Comment: Ok. I already have a token authentication, but it's the 2FA auth which i implemented using the Django-2FA library

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to secure your "microservice external Python script". Am I right?

If it's "external", then why you want to pass user's password? Is this the same database? If it is so why this microservice is external? This is not clear for me :)

Anyway. First of all, you cannot get user's password as an encrypted text that could be send to that external script. See Django documentation how passwords are stored: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords

If you really need to run this script on external server, best solution (n my opinion) for you will be [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) with [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

On your external script you can also write simple middleware to check request's IP and allow only requests from secure IP list

```
ALLOWED_IP = [allowed_ip_list]

class CheckRequestsIP(object):
   def process_request(self, request):
      ip_to_check = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
      if ip_to_check in ALLOWED_IP:
          response = ... # Do your code and prepare response
          return response
      return None
```

And of course in your middleware classes add your class:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
   'path.to.my.CheckRequestsIP',
   ...
)
```

Hope it helps, but if not please let me know. Maybe I just need to better understand your problem :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! I know i wasn't very clear, however let me try to explain this again: X user is using my view. The Django view sends a request to my Flask app. The Flask app must send a response to the Django view with some Data and that user's credentials, because the request must be authenticated. The problem is that i don't know how to replace USERNAME and PASSWORD (see my code) with the user's credentials. Because if the view is used by X user, the credentials must be the credentials of X users. If it is used by Y user, there needs to be the credentials of Y user.

Comment: clear enough :)

Unless you won't save user's password as a plain text (don't do that) it's not possible to get user's passwords via python code. Imagine the situation that your database leak and hacker get all user's passwords... :)

So. User's Token should be enough for you to identify user on Django and Flask app.

Comment: So basically, instead of having 'USERNAME' and 'PASSWORD' there, i should only have 'TOKEN' and there goes the tokens? And in the django view, i'll check if token == correct, something like that?

Comment: To answer some of your questions: it's not really the microservice to be secured, it's also the Django view. Since the data that the microservice sends to Python is a bit sensitive, it must be sent in the safest way possible, another thing is that it must not happen that, for some reason, some users should see the data of another user, by mistakes in my code

Comment: For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For example:

Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b

Comment: If successfully authenticated, TokenAuthentication provides the following credentials. "request.user" will be a Django User instance. "request.auth" will be a rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token instance.

Comment: And most important: If you use TokenAuthentication in production you must ensure that your API is only available over https.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, but in this case, i don't understand how is the external app supposed to get the token of the user that is requesting the service

Comment: Try something like this: curl -X GET http://external_app_with_drf_and_tokenAuth/api/endpoint/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b' and if you implemtnt Tokens correctly and token is right than "return request.user" should send you back user information.